# Disable one option when second is chosen in selectizeInput

Tags: r, select, shiny

I've got a simple shiny application, like here:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

data(iris)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("species", label=NULL, options=list(placeholder="Choose species"), 
                     choices = c(levels(iris$Species), "all"),
                     multiple=TRUE)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tabela")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$tabela <- renderTable({

      if(input$species == "all"){
          iris
      } else{
          iris %>% 
              filter(Species %in% input$species)    
      }
  })
})
```

What I'd like to achive is to block option "all" when one of "virginica", "setosa" or "versiciolor" is already chosen. Option all and something doesn't make any sense...

Do you know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, redefining the reactive output depending on the selection:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)
specChoices <- levels(iris$Species)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$menu <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(input$species)){
      if (any(input$species %in% specChoices)) {
        selectizeInput("species", label=NULL, options=list(placeholder="Choose species"), 
                       choices = specChoices, selected = input$species,
                       multiple=TRUE)
      } else {
        selectizeInput("species", label=NULL, options=list(placeholder="Choose species"), 
                       choices = c(specChoices, "all"), selected = "all",
                       multiple=TRUE)  
      }  
    } else {
      selectizeInput("species", label=NULL, options=list(placeholder="Choose species"), 
                     choices = c(specChoices, "all"),
                     multiple=TRUE)  
    }
  })

  output$tabela <- renderTable({
    if (!is.null(input$species)){
      if("all" %in% input$species ){
        iris
      } else{
        iris %>% 
          filter(Species %in% input$species)    
      }  
    } else {
      iris
    }
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

data(iris)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     uiOutput("menu")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tabela")
    )
  )
))
```